Existence of individual Borel subsets for tuple of measurable functions
Consider a measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$. Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be Borel measurable functions. For an arbitrary Borel set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, let $h: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $h(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{(f(\omega),g(\omega)) \in C}$.
Must there exist Borel subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $h(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{f(\omega) \in A \cap g(\omega) \in B}$?
This seems non-trivial, because it is known that the projection of $C$ to its first $m$ (respectively latter $n$) coordinates is not necessarily Borel in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (respectively $\mathbb{R}^n$), even though $C$ is assumed to be Borel in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. I am self studying some measure theory, and am struggling with this.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is a simple counter-example:
Let $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = x^2+1$ and $g: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x) = x+1$, if $x \geqslant 0$ and $g(x)=1$, if $x < 0$. Clearly they are Borel measurable functions. Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be defined as $C = \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Clearly $C$ is a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
Then, let $h: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $h(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{(f(\omega),g(\omega)) \in C}$. It is easy to see that
$h(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{(f(\omega),g(\omega)) \in C} = \mathbb{I}_{\{\omega \in [0,1] \; : \; f(\omega)=g(\omega)\}}= \mathbb{I}_{\{0,1\}}$
Suppose there are Borel subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{f(\omega) \in A \cap g(\omega) \in B}$. Then, we have $\{0,1\} = \{\omega \in [0,1]: f(\omega) \in A \} \cap \{\omega \in [0,1]: g(\omega) \in B\}$. In particular, $f(0) \in A$ and $f(1) \in A$, so $\{1, 2\} \subseteq A$. So
$$ \{-1,0,1\} \subseteq \{\omega \in [0,1]: f(\omega) \in A \}$$
In similar way, $g(0) \in A$ and $g(1) \in B$, so $\{1, 2\} \subseteq B$. So
$$ [-1,0] \cup \{1\} \subseteq \{\omega \in [0,1]: g(\omega) \in B\} $$
So
$$\{-1,0,1\}  \subseteq \{\omega \in [0,1]: f(\omega) \in A \} \cap \{\omega \in [0,1]: g(\omega) \in B\} = \{0,1\}$$
Contradiction. So, there are no Borel subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{f(\omega) \in A \cap g(\omega) \in B}$.

thank you for the help!
